# How do I do an in-kind transfer of funds from an individual to joint account in Vanguard?

Tags: mutual-funds, vanguard, account-transfer

For a few years I had an individual brokerage account in Vanguard where I invested in some mutual funds. Now I decided to open a joint brokerage account with my wife and transfer these funds to this new account, without having to sell & buy these assets. Is that even possible? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: It might be simplest to add her to your existing account.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, @RonJohn. The only thing that I've found was the "Adding an owner to a non-retirement account" form. When I started filling it out, it prompted me to select the corresponding accounts (a source & a destination), which was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There's a web page https://investor.vanguard.com/investing/rollover-iras-transfers. A link *Start your transfer online* leads me to the page that allows to create a new account. What do you see, when you login as a customer?

Comment: Those options are useful if I wanted to transfer the money or funds from another brokerage account into Vanguard, but that's not my use case.